# How to calculate the expectation of a "ceiling" normal distribution besides Monte Carlo?

Tags: normal-distribution, analytical

Let's say I have a random variable B transformed from a standard normal distribution. When the value is larger than 1, it is set to be 0. Is there an analytical way to get the expectation of random variable B?

Comment: The answer is "yes". However, before giving more details, can I ask if this is a [tag:self-study] question?

Comment: I'll leave my answer in outline form while GeoMatt's question is resolved.

Comment: Yes, it is a self-study question.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, and note that you should as far as possible show an attempt at solving it yourself (in your question) as well as explaining what you've tried to resolve the question yourself (you show no evidence of [research](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in your question). Since I already outline an approach to a solution, if you have no other ideas, you should consider trying that approach. The results/calculations required are completely standard things.

Comment: Please also consider GeoMatt's suggested phrase for describing your problem (see the comment under my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is (in outline form) as follows:

You can write the distribution of $B$ as a [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures) of a [truncated normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) and a variable that's constant at 0.

You can then write an expression for the mean of the truncated normal easily enough, via standard methods, obtaining a result in terms of the density and cdf of a standard normal evaluated at the truncation point (i.e. $-\phi(1)/\Phi(1)\approx -0.2876000$).

The expectation of the mixture is straightforward (via the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), for example), it's the sum of the component expectations times their mixing proportions (component weights). Since the spike at $0$ has expectation $0$, you just end up with the expectation of the truncated normal times its mixing proportion (which proportion is just the denominator of the above expression), leaving you with an expectation of $-\phi(1)$ ($\approx -0.24197$).

Checking via simulation:

```
x <- rnorm(1000000)
mean(ifelse(x>1,0,x))
[1] -0.2419247
```

seems to fit with the analytical calculation $E(B)=-\phi(1)$.

[This is not necessarily the simplest possible way to tackle the problem.]

Comment: I was going to suggest that perhaps a better name than "ceiling" would be "[zero-inflated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-inflation) [truncated normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)" distribution.

Comment: @Geomatt Yes, that would be an excellent description

Comment: @Glen_b Since this is a self-study problem aren't you supposed to wait for the OP to show you how he is approaching the problem and then provide hints?  You gave the OP that advice but did not wait for him to do anything more than say it is self study. He hasn't even tagged it as self study yet. Also your answer is a pretty strong hint.  Maybe you could have just referred him to Wikipedia where the general forms of the truncated normal mean is expressed as well as other moments of the distribution.  StasK did that as an answer to the question "Strictly positive random variables",

Comment: @Michael giving complete solutions for self-study generally a no-no. Hints and guidance are reasonable (whether or not it has been marked as self-study, though usually it's preferable for it to be marked that way first). Whether or not it is closed before changes are made is a matter of some judgement; (I judged the way it was asked as allowing a bit more license in this case). You're certainly free to argue than I gave more of a hint than is suitable -- in response to your comment, I have removed some of the most direct part of the hint.

Comment: Simply, it is a _censored Normal_ , censored above at 1, and the discrete mass recorded at 0 (which is a pity, in a way, as to question design, since the 0 itself will leave the expectation unaffected, and it would be nicer to need to include it, to make sure the mechanics are being done properly).

Comment: @Glen_b how does editing the answer help if the OP has already seen and accepted your answer before the change?

Comment: For the same reason we edit and retag questions -- and even add answers -- after an answer has been accepted: because the expressly stated purpose of the StackExchange network is not simply to answer that one person's question, but to help the next hundred people that read it. So me trying to accommodate your complaint  matters for all those people even if I misjudged it for the asker (which I am not really sure of, but I do try to account for other people's opinion, since I recognize that I make mistakes).  ,,, ctd

Comment: ctd ... [I should add that when I was first writing my answer I didn't think this one was a self-study question -- incorrectly as it turned out.. When I saw that GeoMatt had asked about it, I did reconsider the possibility though, and modified my answer, then when you complained, I modified it again.]